# Scroll в Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2, прокрутка

Всем привет. Нужно организовать скроллинг на сайте, в основе которого лежит Angular2. Собственно, в чем заключается вопрос. Есть список статей, который, естественно подгружается в отдельном компоненте и, соответственно, появляется на странице не моментально(пока ответ с сервера, пока рендеринг). Нужно, чтобы пользователь при просмотре списка статей и перехода на любую из них, при нажатии кнопки "Назад" возвращался к тому месту списка, с которого ушел.

Вариантов было 2.

Первый вариант. При изменении роутинга записывать адрес страницы, с которой уходит пользователь и значение `window.pageYOffset` и через:

```
location: PlatformLocation; 
Location.onPopState();
```

отлавливать нажатие кнопки `back` и через `setTimeout` (дожидаясь пока придет ответ с сервера и все прорисуется) скролить. Но тут проблема в том, что не очень хороший вариант, потому как доподлинно не известно через сколько может прийти ответ и произойдет отрисовка.

Второй вариант, над которым сейчас бьюсь - это через `pushState` попытаться все сделать. Но тут масса заковырок, которые никак не могу обойти. Почему-то перестает работать кнопка "Вперед" и почем-то `window.onpopstate` отрабатывает по несколько раз сразу.

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей, поделитесь опытом. Или направьте в нужное русло.

Comment: а если при ngOnDestroy записывать в localStorage, а при ngOnInit читать?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, проблема в том, что под навигацию используется отдельный сервис. В пределах сервиса и пытаюсь сделать. Сервис для того, чтобы такую навигацию можно было организовать на всех страницах сайта, а не только в статьях.

Comment: так injectable-сервис и пишет-читает localstorage, к нужным компонентам цеплять его, или я совсем не понимаю о чем речь :)

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, нет, Вы не поняли) Речь о том, что есть сервис навигации у нас. Через него всем и нужно рулить. Компонентов очень много, чтобы в них все прописывать. Ведь по факту, у нас есть значение скрола и адрес страницы. Зачем лезть в компоненты.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy вот Вам в помощь, почитайте что это такое, не стоит мутить велосипеды и куда-то что-то сохранять, ангуляр все сделает за Вас, только разберитесь.

Comment: @Artsiom спасибо Вам большое. Буду копать)

Comment: нзч, это Ваш случай, в интернетх много статей интересных

Comment: @Artsiom, здравствуйте. Поискал информацию, но так и не понял, как я с помощью этого инструмента могу сохранить состояние скроллинга и вернутся к этому месту на странице при возврате по кнопке back. 
Скиньте хотя бы одну ссылку на хороший источник.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем `route-reuse-strategy.ts`

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

  private handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

  calcKey ( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot ) {
    let next = route;
    let url = '';
    while ( next ) {
      if ( next.url ) {
        url = next.url.join('/');
      }
      next = next.firstChild;
    }
    return url;
  }

  shouldDetach ( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot ): boolean {
    // console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldDetach', route);
    return true;
  }

  store ( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle ): void {
    // console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:store', route, handle);
      this.handlers[this.calcKey(route)] = handle;
    }

  shouldAttach ( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot ): boolean {
    // console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldAttach', route);
    return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[this.calcKey(route)];
  }

  retrieve ( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot ): DetachedRouteHandle {
    // console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:retrieve', route);
    if ( !route.routeConfig ) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.handlers[this.calcKey(route)];
  }

  shouldReuseRoute ( future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot ): boolean {
    // console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldReuseRoute', future, curr);
    return this.calcKey(curr) === this.calcKey(future);
  }

}
```

Импортим `app.module.ts`

`{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy }`

Далее, если с роутами все нормально, у вас будет сохраняться их состояние. В вашем случае при возврате на главную страницу не будет никаких подгрузок, вы будете возвращаться туда, откуда ушли.

Comment: да. Спасибо большое. Я не обратил на это внимания при первом внедрении(я этот код нашел до Вашей отсылки к нему), но просмотрев, показалось, что абсолютно ничего не изменилось. 
Когда же вы прислали код, я подумал, что все-таки нужное делал и попатался снова более тщательно посмотреть результат. Оказалось, как Вы и сказали,  сейчас компоненты не подгружаются заново, т.е. состояние хранится(этого я первоначально не заметил), но проблема в том, что он не скролит на старую позицию.

Comment: Он скроллит посередине страницы и все. Не пойму даже логики, по которой он скролит. Потому как с главной можно перейти в пост и он проскроллит в самый низ страницы, а вернусь назад - он просто посередине ставит. Каждая итерация "go/back" поднимает на несколько пикселей скролл вверх, а в статье - наоборот, вниз

Comment: посмотрите css ваш, или еще что там есть, что может так двигать, у меня всегда остается как и было)

Comment: и совсем беда пришла, Cannot find primary outlet to load 'ColleaguesListComponent'. При переходах началась такая проблема на другие компоненты. А иногда брюзжит на то, что не может создать дубликат ActivatedRouter

Comment: здесь надо уже настраивать именно под свои роуты, Выше пример для моег оприложения, это lazy + вложенные

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов попробуйте подход без `calcKey` метода для обычного роутинга

Comment: у нас тоже есть lazy подгрузка и вложенные роутинги. Но вот ошибки никак не получается проаназилировать

Comment: Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot created from a different route - вот такие "весёлости"

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов ну я здесь уже не смогу помочь не зная ваших роутов и вообще как все настроено

Comment: ну я же правильно понимаю, что в целом мы создаем этот класс, импортируем в app.module и добавляем в providers:

`providers: [ 
{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy },
...
]`
И все? Больше же ничего нигде подключать/прописывать не нужно?
Router же просто начинает юзать его автоматом после этого. Или я в чем-то ошибаюсь?

Так же прочитал, с чем это может быть связано, рекомендовали проверять по ключу, который добавлять при настройке маршрутов, чтобы потом получить оригинальный ключ для каждого маршрута:
`router.data.key`

Comment: Да, верно понимаете... Да можно по ключу, дальнейшие настройки зависят только от того, что вам надо

Comment: вешал ключи и на основные маршруты и на их дочерние, но почему-то все-равно выдается ошибка.

Comment: Вот здесь почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular

Comment: пример, который он дает в plunker имеет тот же самый недостаток. Крашится на том же самом моменте. при повторном переходе

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов так вы продеюажьте, на каком месте он не может разобрать ключи и восстановить роут, там куча нюансов, нет универсального решения, надо понять какие у вас роуты, где могут возникнуть ошибки и настраивать... я не смогу так ментально вам помочь и написать за вас код

Comment: спасибо за огромную помощь!